# How to get the main class of a Jersey project?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jersey

I would like to create a simple java web application project using Jersey; so I went the framework website, and following the [basic tutorial](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html) I tried to create a new JavaEE application.
First I installed maven, and then I run those line, exactly as specified on the tutorial:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp 
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false 
-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service-webapp -Dpackage=com.example 
-DarchetypeVersion=2.12
```

But then, when I tried to run the application using *mvn exec:java* the build fails and I have the following error:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3:java
> (default-cli) on project simple-service-webapp: The parameters
> 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3:java are
> missing or invalid

Now, where could I get the required Main Class? Is it necessary to run the project on eclipse as well? Thanks for your answer

Comment: You have to define it in your pom (or possibly in the manifest).

Comment: Fine, but what will it contain? Could you give me an example of that? and in the pom file, how do I define it?

Comment: It will contain the class of the project with the `main` you'd like to run it with. The exec task is documented in the Maven docs (and it's searchable on SO as well).